# If for monos $u\leq v$ and $v\leq u$ then their domains are isomorphic

Tags: category-theory, order-theory, morphism, monomorphisms

I'm unable to prove that if a mono $u:B\to A$ is less then mono $v:C\to A$ by $f:B\to C$ with $v\circ f=u$ and also
$v\leq u$ by $u\circ g=v$ then $B\cong C$ by using some morphisms as above, but I believe that this holds. Is there a hint how this $\cong$ may look like together with a hint that it is $\cong$ ? This is certainly true in the category of Sets and functions but I suspect that it holds in general. Also, I think that this is further more equivalent to $u=v\circ \theta$ for some $\theta$ being an isomorphism. How can I see this equivalence ?

Comment: hint: with the data you listed, do you have any morphisms between $B$ and $C$? Do they compose to the identity?

Comment: @S.C. I have also thought along these lines. I do have $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ but I cannot immediately see that they compose to $\mathbf{id}_A$.

Comment: @user122424 You’re almost done! Hint: $u$ and $v$ are monos.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question and deleted my answer

Comment: @azif00 I've got the first part of my OQ: $vfg=ug=v=v \mathbf{id}_C$. What about my last sentence in my OQ ?

Comment: @user122424 If I understand correctly, just take $\theta=f$.

Comment: @azif00 Everything was trivial, after all.

Comment: @azif00 Is this line entirely correct including the $C$-index: $vfg=ug=v=v\circ \mathbf{id}_C$ ?

Comment: @user122424 That is correct. I just wrote an answer that summarizes everything in the comments.

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4107996/why-a-hookrightarrow-b-hookrightarrow-c-simeq-a-implies-a-simeq-b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u \colon B \to A$ and $v \colon C \to A$ monomorphisms in a category. Then the following are equivalent:

1. There are morphisms $f \colon B \to C$ and $g \colon C \to B$ such that $u=vf$ and $v=ug$.
2. There is an isomorphism $\theta \colon B \to C$ such that $u=v\theta$.

*Proof*: If we assume (1), it suffices to prove that $f$ is an isomorphism (so, $\theta=f$ works for (2)). Indeed, since
$$
u\text{id}_B=u=vf=(ug)f=u(gf)
$$
and $u$ is mono, then $gf=\text{id}_B$. Also, since
$$
v\text{id}_C=v=ug=(vf)g=v(fg)
$$
and $v$ is mono, then $fg=\text{id}_C$. Hence, $f$ is an isomorphism.

On the other hand, if we assume (2), then the morphisms $f=\theta$ and $g=\theta^{-1}$ works for (1).